# Indefinite integral (not elementarily solvable?)

Tags: calculus, integration

I wanted to ask if there is a straightforward way to say that the following $$\int\frac{x \cos^2 x}{\sin x}dx$$

is not elementarily computable (I tried different things, among which change of variables, integration by parts, but nothing really seems to work).

Comment: Multiply numerator and denominator by $\sin x,$ obtain a primitive of $\cos^2 d(\cos x)/(1-\cos^2x)$ and you are ready for an integration by parts.

Comment: @GérardLetac What does the $d$ mean in $\cos^2 d$?

Comment: @DialFrost it's a typo, it's meant to say $\cos^2 x \cdot d(\cos x)$ in the numerator

Comment: Integration by parts gives us $$I = x\cos x - \sin x -x\tanh^{-1}(\cos x) + \int \tanh^{-1}(\cos x)\:dx$$ That last integral is definitely non elementary

Comment: @NinadMunshi er what does the $d$ mean still? sorry I don't really understand it

Comment: @DialFrost what does $d$ mean in front of $x$ in $dx$?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oh is it just a short form of $d/dx$? (d stands for derivative or differentiation) Just was curious because I never really saw $d$ without the $x$ behind it

Comment: Kind of. The $d(\cdot)$ means we are integrating with respect to whatever follows the $d$. Instead of integrating with respect to $x$, we are integrating with respect to $\cos x$. To contrast, consider $$\int \cos x \:dx = \sin x + C$$ versus $$\int \cos x \:d(\cos x) = \frac{1}{2}\cos^2 x + C$$

Comment: @user367976, if your integral $\;\int\frac{x\cos^2 x}{\sin x}\mathrm dx\;$ were elementarily computable, then also $\;\int\left(\frac{x\cos^2 x}{\sin x}+x\sin x\right)\mathrm dx\;$ would be elementarily computable, but it is equal to $\;\int\frac x{\sin x}\mathrm dx\,$ which cannot actually be expressed by elementary functions.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is not elementary though it can be expressed in terms of dilogarithm function as

$$
\boxed{\int \frac{x \cos ^2 x}{\sin x} d x =x \cos x+\sin x+x \ln \left(\frac{1-e^{i x}}{1+e^x}\right) +i\left[\operatorname{Li_2}\left(-e^{i x}\right)-\operatorname{Li_2}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right]+C \;}
$$

Using integration by parts, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{x \cos ^2 x}{\sin x} d x 
= & \int x \cot x d(\sin x) \\
= & x \cos x-\int\left(\cos x-\frac{x}{\sin x}\right) d x \\
= & x \cos x+\sin x+\int \frac{x}{\sin x} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
By complex number, we transform the last integral into
$$
J=\int \frac{x}{\sin x} d x=2 i \int \frac{x}{e^{i x}-e^{-i x}} d x= 2 i \int \frac{x e^{i x}}{e^{2 i x}-1} d x
$$
Using integration by parts, we have
$$
J=\int x \, d \left(\ln \left(\frac{1-e^{i x}}{1+e^{i x}}\right)\right) =x \ln \left(\frac{1-e^{i x}}{1+e^{i x}}\right)-\int \ln \left(\frac{1-e^{i x}}{1+e^{i x}}\right)d x
$$
For the last integral,
$$
\int \ln \left(1-e^{i x}\right) d x \stackrel{y=e^{ix}}{=}  \int \frac{\ln (1-y)}{-i y} d y= i \operatorname{Li_2}\left(y\right) =i \operatorname{Li_2}\left(e^{i x}\right)+C_1
$$
Similarly,
$$
\int \ln \left(1+e^{i x}\right) d x \stackrel{z=-e^{ix}}{=}  \int \frac{\ln (1-z)}{i z} d z
=-i \operatorname{Li_2}\left(z\right)
=-i \operatorname{Li_2}\left(-e^{i x}\right)+C_2
$$
Now we can conclude that
$$
\int \frac{x \cos ^2 x}{\sin x} d x =x \cos x+\sin x+x \ln \left(\frac{1-e^{i x}}{1+e^x}\right) +i\left[\operatorname{Li_2}\left(-e^{i x}\right)-\operatorname{Li_2}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right]+C 
$$

However, it is not easy to prove that $\operatorname{Li_2}\left(-e^{i x}\right)-\operatorname{Li_2}\left(e^{i x}\right)$ is not elementary. Who can help?

Comment: Even if we know $\operatorname{Li_2}$ is not elementary, presumably even more work would be required to show that the combination $\left[\operatorname{Li_2}\left(-e^{i x}\right)-\operatorname{Li_2}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right]$ is not elementary.

Comment: Agree! It is hard to show this.